# I want to turn a Windows 10 machine into a Media center Kiosk

Tags: windows-10, media-player, kiosk

I have a Windows 10 PC, and I want to turn it into a touch screen Media Center kiosk.

Basically, I want it to be a media player that lets an end user control ways played. The 'program' should load up like a 'media library' program, very similar to the apple kindle library. You should be able to click on some media, it should play, and you should be able to back out and go to another show/movie/etc.

- Runs on Windows 10, 8GM ram
- Ideally free
- Works with touch screen
- Plays most mainstream media files (MP4, AVI, MOV, etc)

I want to put it in my car so the kids can click on the screen and pick something to watch without needed a mouse or keyboard to navigate thru the shows/movies available. Something similar to this but for media files "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4IvEorrqMnY"

I've looked up different software and haven't found one that really worked, any recommendations? Even a DIY solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think [KODI](https://kodi.tv/) (was called XBMC earlier) would be a good solution. It's available for many different operating systems (including windows) and platforms and works great. AFAIK it also supports touch input.

Comment: ill give it a try